# How do I launch a standalone web app from mobile safari using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I am developing a standalone web app that installs on iphone homescreen.
It has a calendar function that the user can download an ***.ics** file directly into the iphone.
However, that cannot be done from within the standalone web app, so I have a punch out url to mobile safari so that it will work.
All that works fine...
However, after the ics file is loaded into the calendar and closed, it returns to the mobile safari page where I in turn close that by using `onclick='self.close()'`. That works fine too...
After that page closes I want to then launch back into standalone app so the user is returned to where they were...

How do I launch my own web app from a mobile safari javascript code?
All the searching shows me how to go from standalone to mobile safari,...I want mobile safari to standalone.

I have seen the **windows.location="myapp://myparam"**  but cannot find proper syntax to get it to work.
What is the syntax for this?

Any other solution is well received too...will need to find Android solution too, but it is not as crucial...

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that you can do it.  Native apps can register a URL scheme, but I don't believe that home screen web apps can

Comment: Arrggg,...that is crazy that you can't launch a standalone web app by title or something...  Is there a way to go back to an app that is is open but not the active "window"...?